# mapstruct protobuf3 mapping a map

Tags: protocol-buffers, mapstruct

I am trying to use mapstruct to map my DTO to protobuf generated class.
This class contains a map but this cause an Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.putAll(Collections.java:1463)
```

I am not sure how to bypass this.

this is my mapper function

```
@Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "profiles", source = "profiles"),
  MyClassMessage.Builder convertToBuilder(MyClassDto myClassDto);
```

it generate this code

```
if ( builder.getProfiles() != null ) {
  Map<String, Object> map = stringInterpreterProfileMapToStringInterpreterProfileMessageMap( interpreterSettingDto.getProfiles() );
  if ( map != null ) {
    builder.getProfiles().putAll( map ); // <-- this cause the exception
  }
 }
```

But i think it should be something like this instread

```
if ( builder.getProfiles() != null ) {
            Map<String, Object> map = stringInterpreterProfileMapToStringInterpreterProfileMessageMap( interpreterSettingDto.getProfiles() );
            if ( map != null ) {
                builder.putAllProfiles( map );
            }
        }
```

How should i tell mapstruct to do that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the solution i found was to something like

```
@Mapping(target = "mutableProfiles", source = "profiles"),
@Mapping(target = "profiles", ignore = true),
```

The first line will use the mutable map and add the collection
and the 2nd will tell mapstruct to not try to map profile since its already done.

Comment: this method has been depricated by protobuf. but hopefully, mapstruct will fix the underlying problem before google removes the method altogether.

Comment: I ran across this again when trying to map two protobuf objects. For those finding the same you will want to add.

Comment: what is mutableProfiles. In your original post you only have it as 
```@Mapping(target = "profiles", source = "profiles"),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported within MapStruct. However, there is an open feature request for it see issue [#1343](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1343)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like:

```
@Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "putAllProfiles", source = "profiles"),
  MyClassMessage.Builder convertToBuilder(MyClassDto myClassDto);
```